# How to not display <li> node if input text field is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I click the result button without filling in the field it will display the list node like this `<li></li>`

If possible I want the list node to not show in the div when the input field is empty. While if the input field has value it will have `<li>text</li>`.

I would appreciate any help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_fields_button");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x <= max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="clonedInput"><input class="m-input" id="data_item' + x++ + '"  type="text" name="myText" style="width: 1000px"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    $('.result_button').trigger('click');
  });
});

//change the code below
$('.result_button').click(function() {
  var input = $(".m-input");
  var list = "<ul>";

  for (let index = 0; index < $(input).length; index++) {
    const element = $(input)[index];
    list += "<li>" + $(element).val() + "</li>";

  }

  list += "</ul>";
  $(".trigger").html(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_fields_button">Add +</button>
    <div class="clonedInput">
      <input class="m-input" id="data_item" type="text" name="myText" style="width: 1000px"><button class="remove_field removeLi">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div>
    <button type="button" value="Result" class="result_button">Result</button>
  </div>
  <div class="trigger">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, just add one extra condition i.e : `if ($(element).val() != "") { list += "<li>" + $(element).val() + "</li>"; }` . Working code check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8mkyxq25/)

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you just have to make sure that element is not empty :

```
for (let index = 0; index < $(input).length ; index++) {
           const element = $(input)[index];

            if($(element).val().length > 0) {
                 list += "<li>" + $(element).val() + "</li>";
            }
       }
```